# Return the SOAP Complex Types defined in the WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've created a WSDL with some complex data types in it, en excerpt is below.

The SOAP server is using PHP and my client is C#.  I can connect to the soap server fine with C# and see all the types, I can create the API request header and call the methods etc etc.

The problem I'm having is, how do I return, for example, an object like GetAccountFundsResp from the PHP SOAP server. Whatever I try I'm just getting a null object in C#

```
<xsd:complexType abstract="true" name="APIResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="header" nillable="true" type="types:APIResponseHeader"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="APIResponseHeader">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="types:APIErrorEnum"/>
        <xsd:element name="minorErrorCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="sessionToken" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="APIErrorEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="OK"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="INTERNAL_ERROR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType abstract="true" name="APIRequest">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="header" nillable="true" type="types:APIRequestHeader"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="APIRequestHeader">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="clientStamp" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:element name="sessionToken" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="GetAccountFundsResp">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="types:APIResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="availBalance" nillable="false" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element name="balance" nillable="false" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="types:GetAccountFundsErrorEnum"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="GetAccountFundsErrorEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="OK"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="API_ERROR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="GetAccountFundsReq">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="types:APIRequest"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Returning objects and arrays.

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: I created an object with the same format as defined in the wsdl, instantiated it and returned it.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind.  I just found nusoap and it solved all my problems :)

Comment: It isn't very helpful to just answer _Never mind, I found the solution_ if you're not sharing the _solution_ in your answer, and how you accomplished it.